# rethinkdb aggregate counts, should I have a count field or just run the aggregation count function

Tags: rethinkdb

Regarding performance - is it advisable to have a totalCount field updated rather than running queries with aggregation?  For instance let's say there is a ChatRoom collection each with an emedded online users collection.  And we want to get a query result of rooms with total user count for each room.

I know in mongo they advise you to increment a totalUsers property on the room itself rather than running a count() query on ChatRoom.users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of the users array.  If it's large then having a running count field will be much faster, if it's small then it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: it should be less than a hundred max in any room and there would be up to a few hundred rooms.  I've elaborated a bit of the use case in this questtion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34190913/how-to-get-length-of-embedded-array-in-a-rethink-query-projection

Comment: Counting 100 elements should be a pretty small percentage of total time.  I wouldn't bother adding a `totalCount` field unless you're having performance problems and trying to optimize.